# selenium arguments to chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am running selenium tests using nightwatch. Here's how I start selenium:

```
java -jar /opt/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--use-gl=osmesa" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.chrome.bin=/usr/bin/google-chrome  -log /home/jenkins-user/log/selenium.log &
```

What other options should I be passing to chrome to make sure that 
- security alerts are disabled
- I don't get the error "Are you sure you want to leave this page"

What options -Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--use-gl=osmesa" is best practice to send to crome?

For example, I see that selenium/chrome is not playing my video players. What should I do to get them played?